# Difference between eurodollar and 2 year note futures

Tags: portfolio-management, futures, treasuries, bond-futures, eurodollars

What's the difference between these instruments? I know that the Eurodollar is for dollars outside of the US, but is there any material difference other than contract size when it comes to trading each respective futures (in terms of volatility or profit?)

Comment: The Eurodollar rate that the futures contracts are based on is for 3-month loans, which is a different duration than a 2 year bond. So they are not perfect substitutes by any means.

Comment: One is (credit) risk free, one has credit risk. That has at times been important - GFC, for example.

Comment: 'eurodollars' is an unfortunately overloaded term in financial markets, and can mean many different things. Please clarify.